# Prove that $x_{n}$ is convergent if $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq(\frac45)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The question says; prove the sequence $x_{n}$ given by:

$\left | x_{n+1} - x_{n}\right| \leq (\frac{4}{5})^n \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N} $

is convergent.

Here is how I approached the problem:
Since the difference between the terms applies to all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then we know that it is a Cauchy sequence (specifically, a contractile sequence) where we can assume that $\left| x_2 - x_1 \right|=1 $ then $K = \frac{4}{5} <1$

Also since for large values of $n$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\frac{4}{5})^n = 0$ so the constant $(\frac{4}{5})^n$ can replace $\varepsilon$ in the criteria for contractive sequence:

$\left | x_{n+1} - x_{n}\right| \leq \varepsilon $

Then we can have, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left|x_{n+1} - x_{n} \right| = 0$
which is a convergent sequence using the contraction principle.

However, it seems like I should have used another method that uses similar idea but explicitly shows that the difference between $\left|x_{n+1}-x_{n} \right| \leq \frac{4}{5}\left|x_{n}-x_{n-1} \right|$ and so on until I get to $\left | x_{n+1} - x_{n}\right| \leq (\frac{4}{5})^n \left| x_2 - x_1 \right|$.

I would like to get some feedback and the what are the major flaws in my solution. Suggestions are very welcome

Comment: Abstract duplicate of [Prove that if $ |a\_n-a\_{n-1}| < \frac{1}{2^{n+1} }$ and $a\_0=\frac12$, then $\{a\_n\}$ converges to $0<a<1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243761/prove-that-if-a-n-a-n-1-frac12n1-and-a-0-frac12-then-a).

Comment: It seems to me that you've confused some concepts, so let me ask you this: have you seen explicitly that if $0<c<1$ and $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<c^n$ then $(x_n)$ converges? You hint at Cauchy sequences; can you show that such a sequence is Cauchy?

Comment: @CameronBuie, this is a proof-verification, so it's not a duplicate even if the topics are equivalent.

Comment: @JonathanY. I think if we said $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<c^n \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then why not? I thought this is an enough to say that the sequence is a contractive and hence it converges.

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing (think of $x_{2n}=x_{2n+1}=c^{2n+1}$), but close enough. But then, there's really no point in the exercise unless some of these things have been left for you to verify on your own (whether you came across it in a book or from an instructor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you are saying is not enough. For example, the sequence $$ x_n=1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n $$ satisfies that $ |x_n-x_{n+1}|=\frac1{n+1}$, which approaches $0$, and yet the sequence [diverges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29).

(There is also the obvious typo that $\bigl(\frac45\bigr)^n$ is *not* a constant.)

You are not given nearly enough information to find the limit of the sequence, so really the most direct way (the only way?) of verifying convergence is to argue that the sequence is Cauchy. (I assume you are working on the reals, or at least in some complete metric (normed?) space, so the Cauchy criterion ensures convergence. If this is not the case, one can produce easy counterexamples.)

OK, to check that the sequence is Cauchy, we need to bound $|x_n-x_m|$ (not just $|x_n-x_{n+1}|$), in a way that ensures that $|x_n-x_m|$ can be made arbitrarily small, as long as we restrict $n,m$ to sufficiently large values.

The obvious attempt (really, again, the only thing we can do) is to use the triangle inequality. For concreteness, suppose $n<m$. We then have that 
 $$ |x_n-x_m|\le |x_n-x_{n+1}|+|x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}|+\dots+|x_{m-1}-x_m|. $$
Using the bounds we are given, this gives us that 
 $$ |x_n-x_m|\le\left(\frac45\right)^n+\left(\frac45\right)^{n+1}+\dots+\left(\frac45\right)^{m-1}. $$
It is here that the specific numbers $\bigl(\frac45\bigr)^n$ become useful. If instead all we had is that $|x_n-x_{n+1}|\to0$, we would not be able to control $|x_n-x_m|$. However, in this case, we [have](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/seq_induction/advanced-sequences-series/v/formula-for-finite-geometric-series) that 
 $$ |x_n-x_m|\le \left(\frac45\right)^n\frac{1-\left(\frac45\right)^{m-n}}{1-\frac45}\le\left(\frac45\right)^n\frac1{1-\frac45}=5\left(\frac45\right)^n. $$
The latter expression can be made as small as desired as long as $n$ is large enough. That is: For any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that, provided that $N<n\le m$, we have that $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$. This is precisely what it means for the sequence to be Cauchy.

---

Of course, if you already have established a result ensuring the convergence of a sequence satisfying $|x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}|\le K|x_n-x_{n+1}|$ for all $n$ and some constant $K<1$, then you can readily conclude that the sequence converges. Anyway, if you have such a lemma, most likely its proof was along the lines of the argument I gave.

Comment: Thank you for providing a detailed answer to the questions and the critique of my answer

Comment: Regarding the remark at the end, was I mistaken in my last comment to @Logarithm (above)? It still appears to me that the two conditions (though ensuring convergence in pretty much the same way) aren't equivalent.

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I just a minor correction in the last term of the sequence should have a minus sign not addition so no one get confused $|x_{m−1}-x_m|$.

Comment: @Logarithm Thanks for spotting the typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Cauchy Sequence and (assuming $\;m\ge n\;$ )

$$|x_m-x_n|=|x_m-x_{m-1}+x_{m-1}-x_{m-2}+x_{m-2}-x_{m-3}+\ldots x_{n+1}-x_n|\le$$

$$\le\sum_{k=0}^{m-n-1}|x_{m-k}-x_{m-k-1}|\le\sum_{k=0}^{m-n-1}\left(\frac45\right)^{m-k-1}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification.